# How to detect last update in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, click

Have 2 labels in Html that allows a user to choose 1 number in each. How do I check which box is entered last and the value entered in Javascript? Also, how can I change the value of what the user entered if I want to?

```
<div class="text1">
   <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Decimal) %>
</div>

 <div class="text2">
   <%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Decimal) %>
</div>
```

How can I find which textbox was the latest changed? Is what I am doing right?

```
   var change1 = document.getElementById('Text1').lastModified;
   var change2 = document.getElementById('Text2').lastModified;
   if(change1.value > change2.value)
    //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
window.onload = function(){
var one = document.getElementsByClassName("text1")[0].children[0];
var two = document.getElementsByClassName("text2")[0].children[0];

var lastChanged = null;
var input1value, input2value;

one.onkeypress = function(e){
    input1value = e.target.value;
    lastChanged = 1;
    console.log("lastChanged was ", lastChanged, " the value is ", input1value);
};

two.onkeypress = function(e){
    input2value = e.target.value;
    lastChanged = 2;
    console.log("lastChanged was ", lastChanged, " the value is ", input2value);
    };
};
```

You can update the value of an input element by updating its value property